# How can I find acronym in a text?

Tags: ruby, string, include, acronym

My project reads many files (these files have title text and sections) and should find the title of the files that contain an acronym. This is my docs class:

```
class Doc
  def initialize(id, secciones)
    @id, @secciones = id, secciones
  end
  def to_s
    result = "" + @id.to_s + "\n" + @secciones.to_s
    return result
  end
  def tiene_acronimo(acr)
    puts "a ver si tiene acronimos el docu.."
    tiene_acronimo = false
    secciones.each do |seccion|
      if seccion.tiene_acronimo(acr)
        tiene_acronimo = true
      end
    end
    return tiene_acronimo
  end
  attr_accessor :id
  attr_accessor :secciones
end
```

And this my sections class:

```
class Section
  def initialize ()
    @title = ""
    @text = ""   
  end
  def tiene_acronimo(acr)
    return title.include?(acr) || text.include?(acr)
  end
end
```

And this my method:

```
def test()
  results = Array.new
  puts "Dame el acronimo"
  acr = gets
  documentos_cientificos.each do |d|
  if d.tiene_acronimo(acr)
    results << d
  end  
end
```

The method gets an acronym and should find all documents that contain it. The method `inclue?` [sic] ingores the upcase and returns `true` if the docs contain any substring like the acronym. For example:

```
Multiple sclerosis (**MS**), also known as # => `true`
Presenting signs and sympto**ms** # => `false` (but `include?` returns `true`)
```

How I can find an acronym more easily?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some regex with the match function.  The following regex will find a match if the content contains the FULL word provided.  It will ignore substrings, and it will be case sensitive.

```
arc = "MS"
title = "Multiple sclerosis (MS), also known as"
text = "Presenting signs and symptoms"

title.match(/\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/) # => #<MatchData "MS">
text.match(/\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/) # => nil
```

or equivalently

```
title.match(/\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/).to_a.size > 0 # => true
text.match(/\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/).to_a.size > 0 # => false
```

...so you could redefine your function as:

```
def tiene_acronimo(acr)
  regex_to_match = /\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/
  has_acr = false
  if (title.match(regex_to_match)) || (text.match(regex_to_match))
    has_acr = true
  end

  return has_acr
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to ruby, this code works when i declared the var acr ="MS", but when I ask for the value on the screen("acr = gets" and i put MS) is not working. It's weird because I enter the same value... it is as if they are different formats... thanks :)

Comment: When you use gets, a newline character is appended to the end of the input.  You can change the line `regex_to_match = /\b#{Regexp.escape(acr)}\b/` to `regex_to_match = /\b#{Regexp.escape(acr.strip)}\b/` to get rid of the newline character and just check against the entered text.